# Google Maps Angular loop through callback to show multiple markers

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, callback, google-maps-markers, ionic-framework

I'm trying to display markers on a map, but I am running in to difficulty, I'm not too skilled in the use of callbacks, can someone help me out thanks? I want multiple markers to show where different games are.

I'm using a rest api to retrieve the game details from the db, and I know this works, it's just after I retrieve them I can no longer access the data that has just been retrieved.

I am using ionic (Angular) and I am sure there is probably a better way of doing this. What is the best way to use a loop? If anyone could point out how I could improve my code. Here is what my controller for the map looks like

```
.controller('MapController', function($scope, $ionicLoading, gameFactory) {
  $scope.initialise = function() {
...//set up map 
    });
$scope.map = map;
};
      $scope.showGameMarkers = function() {
    var map = document.getElementById("map");
        gameFactory.getGames().success(function(data) {
        //at this stage the data variable contains the details of my game
           angular.forEach(data, function(key, data) {
           //now data is empty
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.locationLatitude, data.locationLongitude); 
        console.log("latlang = "+latLng);
        // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            title: data.locationName,
            setMap : map
        });
      });
  }).error(function(data) {
      console.log("no games");
  });

  };
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("map"), 'load', $scope.initialise());
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("map"), 'load', $scope.showGameMarkers());
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have your key and data parameters reversed in your forEach loop. According to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach it should be

```
angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) {
    ...
}
```